# Javascript - updating an object property with another value from the same object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'jdoe', currentDayHours: null, totalHours: [{ task: 'cleaning', hours: 10}, { task: 'reading', hours: 2 }]}
```

I am trying to create a function that will update the `currentDayHours` based on the task parameter passed to the function.  So for example, if "cleaning" is passed to the function, the expected outcome of the object should be:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'jdoe', currentDayHours: 10, totalHours: [{ task: 'cleaning', hours: 10}, { task: 'reading', hours: 2 }]}
```

I'm still new to javascript but I think I should use `foreach` and `filter`, but not sure how to use both with each other. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: at least show us some code that you have attempted / tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Direct property access is enough.  Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object.

```js
data = { id: 1, name: 'jdoe', currentDayHours: null, totalHours: [{ task: 'cleaning', hours: 10}, { task: 'reading', hours: 2 }]}

const updateHours = (data,key) => {
  data.currentDayHours = (data.totalHours.find(({task})=>task===key)||[]).hours
  return data
}

console.log(updateHours(data,'cleaning'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.find()` to find the task object in the `totalHours` array, and then use that object's `hours` to assign to `currentDayHours`.

If you want to modify the object *in-place*, you can do this:

```js
function updateCurrentDayHours(obj, taskName) {
    const task = obj.totalHours.find(t => t.task === taskName)
    if (task) obj.currentDayHours = task.hours
}
```

If you want to return a cloned object, you can use a deepClone function provided by some libaries like lodash. Here I'm using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` for simplicity.

```js
function updateCurrentDayHours(obj, taskName) {
    const task = obj.totalHours.find(t => t.task === taskName)
    if (task) {
        const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
        clone.currentDayHours = task.hours
        return clone
    }
}
```